# Xfce settings manager crashing

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

Running an up to date Ubuntu Studio distro with Xfce 4.8, every time I try to open the settings manager nothing seems to happen. 
Running xfce4_settings_manager from terminal returns

> xfce4-settings-manager: symbol lookup error: xfce4-settings-manager: undefined symbol: xfce_dialog_show_help_with_version

Any suggestion? I tried searching the forums but nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

You could try from the terminal enter this:

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then reinstall ubuntu-desktop from the terminal enter this:

```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xfce
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: installing xfce-desktop returns "unable to locate package"

Comment: Have you tryed sudo dpkg --reconfigure system-manager

Answer (score 1):

You have somehow caught a mixture of ubuntu 12.04 (xfce 4.8) and 14.04 (xfce 4.11) packages.

On 14.04:

```
$ readelf -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxfce4ui-2.so.0.0.0 | grep xfce_dialog_show_help
328: 0000000000008b70     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 xfce_dialog_show_help
341: 0000000000008710  1109 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 xfce_dialog_show_help_wit
```

Either install / upgrade package `libxfce4ui-2-0` to the 4.11 version or purge some PPAs to reset back to 4.8.

Comment: ran an install --reinstall libxfce4ui-2-0 and apparently it was already up to date "Unpacking libxfce4ui-2-0 (4.11.1-2ubuntu1) over (4.11.1-2ubuntu1) ..."
Any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you install any PPAs or other package sources?

Comment: Not recently nor anything I can remember. Every update was done through the system update tool

Comment: This was a useful answer from aquaherd - I ran into a very similar problem with old xfce, but on slackware. Upgrading to more recent xfce packages while eliminating the old solved the same issue (well almost the same).